# Remove all files from history that are not in working tree

Tags: git, branch, git-diff, git-filter-branch, git-rm

Lots of answers on StackExchange deal with removing a given file from all commits in the history with something like:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty -d /dev/shm/scratch \
 --index-filter "git rm --cached -f --ignore-unmatch filename" \
 --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

However my repo had lots of data pushing into it over time and I am hoping to significantly reduce its size by filtering out all files that are not in the present working tree.

From the man page this can be done against the index via:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

From what I can gather the first part gets the names of all deleted files which the second part removes them from the cached version.

What I can't quite work out is how to change the filter-branch version of the rm command would be changed to ensure that it compares that version of the index against the head (thus removing all deleted files).

The purpose of this would be to remove all files, in the history, which are not present in the current working tree.

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose of this would be to remove all files, in the history, which are not present in the current working tree.

Although you're using `git filter branch`, you may want to consider using the BFG Repo Cleaner (a faster, simpler alternative), which has behaviour quite similar to this out of the box. There are slight differences:

- You are, I think, looking to delete all history of any file that is not in your current HEAD commit - that is, the full file tree of your latest commit
- With the BFG, you can delete all versions of any files you specify by size or name (including wildcards), and it will [only preserve file versions that are in your latest commit](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#protected-commits).

...so if you use:

```
$ bfg --delete-files "*.png"
```

...all `.png` files will be removed from your project history - except for the particular version of any `.png` file that is in your current commit. Note that if a particular version of a file occurs *once* anywhere in your history, it might as well occur a thousand times, it will still have the same storage requirements as far as git is concerned.

> my repo had lots of data pushing into it over time and I am hoping to significantly **reduce its size**

As your overall aim is reduce size, so long as you achieve that, you're happy! So you could run:

```
$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10K
```

...and that would remove all (non-current) files bigger than 10 kilobytes in size - it would reduce repo size a lot- and as side benefit keep the history of smaller files that weren't problematic.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).*

Comment: I was looking at bfg as an alternative, however I thought it was only for deleting singular files, throughout the git history. So running `bfg --delete-files "*"` would delete everything that isn't in the current tree, however would it also delete any history of files in the current tree?

Comment: Thus to delete everything not in the current working tree, it would be something like `bfg --delete-files <every file not in current working tree`?